# What is the proper way to detect Bootstrap dropdown menu selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, toggle

Using Twitter Bootstrap and the [Javascript Dropdowns feature](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns), what is the proper way to hide the menu on the `.dropdown-menu li a` click event, as well as update some property on what was selected, without that `<a>` click event firing and going off to its `href` value?

Here's the way I'm doing it now for lack of better documentation on this. However, is there a recommended way that the Twitter Bootstrap authors would rather that I do this? I mean, it would be great if all I would have to do is add some property on the menu item and then it automatically hides the dropdown and updates a property on the dropdown-toggle control.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#listoptions A').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#listoptions').removeClass('open');
  var sWhich = $(this).attr('id');
  if (sWhich == 'addnewlist') {
    addNewList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'renamelist') {
    renameList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'exportlist') {
    exportList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'importlist') {
    importList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'emptylist') {
    emptyList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'deletelist') {
    deleteList();
  }
  return false;
});
</script>

<div id="listoptions" class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-target="#" data-toggle="dropdown" 
  aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu align-left" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="addnewlist" role="menuitem">Add New List...</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="renamelist" role="menuitem">Rename List...</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="exportlist" role="menuitem">Export List...</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="importlist" role="menuitem">Import Into List...</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="emptylist" role="menuitem">Empty List</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="deletelist" role="menuitem">Delete List</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#listoptions a').click(function(e){}); i think not 'A',it is 'a'
or $('#listoptions').children().find('a').click(function(){});

Comment: The capital A works. Typically I do caps in selectors for addressing HTML tags so that it is easier to read.

Comment: $('#listoptions').children().find('a').click(function(e){}) try it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to remove the class open as bootstrap does it after selection.

```
$('.dropdown-menu li a').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    executeAction(id);
});

executeAction = function (id) {
    switch (id) {
        case "addnewlist":
            addNewList();
            break;
        case "renamelist":
            renameList();
            break;
        case "exportlist":
            exportList();
            break;
        case "importlist":
            importList();
            break;
        case "emptylist":
            emptyList();
            break;
        case "deletelist":
            deleteList();
            break;
    }
}
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yk1z8bek/2/)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#listoptions a')` will be treated as next absolute children of `#listoption` so you have to find `a` in `#listoption`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#listoptions').children().find('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#listoptions').removeClass('open');
  var sWhich = $(this).attr('id');
  if (sWhich == 'addnewlist') {
    addNewList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'renamelist') {
    renameList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'exportlist') {
    exportList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'importlist') {
    importList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'emptylist') {
    emptyList();
  } else if (sWhich == 'deletelist') {
    deleteList();
  }
  return false;
});
</script>
```